# grid.selection.getSelected().length on selecting one row

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have created a dojox.grid.DataGrid and i want to perform some operations on the rows selected by the user, so, i have placed an alert to get the no. of rows selected by the user.

I am using :
var noofrows=grid.selection.getSelected().length;
alert(noofrows); 
to get the number of rows selected by the user in the grid.
When the user selects one row the above statement alerts 0 but it should pop-up 1 as 1 row is selected by user.
When user selects multiple rows it pop-ups the correct number of rows selected by the user.

After selecting multiple rows(right result is getting poped-up) when user selects one row it pop-ups the correct output i.e.: 1.

So, basically the issue is when user selects one row for the first time it pop-ups the wrong output(i.e :0).

Here is the grid creation code :

```
<table id="AA.FavouritesGrid" dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid"
    region="center"
    jsId="table"
    id="table"
    store="AAFavouritesStore"  style="font-size:30px;width:100%;padding:0px;display:0px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <%
            String userCode ="";
            userCode = request.getUserPrincipal().getName();
            try {
                Map<String,String> columnNameLabelMap=model.getDynamicNameLabelmap("Favourites", userCode, locale);

                // Loop round columns ordered by user
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : columnNameLabelMap.entrySet()){
                    int width = columnDataById.get(entry.getKey()).getWidth();
                    columnDataById.remove(entry.getKey());
            %>
            <th field=<%=entry.getKey() %> width="<%=width%>" height="22px" nowrap="nowrap"><%=entry.getValue()%></th>

            <%
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

                System.out.println(e);
            }

            // Present any left over columns in default order
            for (ColumnData entry : columnDataById.values()){
            %>
            <th field=<%=entry.getId() %> width="<%=entry.getWidth()%>" height="22px" nowrap="nowrap"><%=entry.getName()%></th>

            <%
            }
            %>

            <th field="path" hidden="true"></th>
            <th field="underwritingYear"  hidden="true" ></th>
            <th  field="lpRCTLobDesc"     hidden="true" ></th>
            <th  field="lpRCTLob"    hidden="true" ></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

favContextMenu = dojo.connect(dijit.byId("AA.FavouritesGrid"),"onCellContextMenu", favouritesGridOnContextMenu );

function favouritesGridOnContextMenu(e) {

alert(table.selection.getSelected().length);
}

Please help to resolve the problem

Thanks

Comment: Question is not clear, Please edit the same so that we can get what do you mean.

Comment: edited..please help to resolve the problem

Comment: Please Post some code so that we can get where is the error.

Comment: let me know if you require more information

Comment: I have found something interesting, Actually their are two things :user first click(left click) on a row and then right clicks , it return the correct output(i.e: 1). If user directly right clicks on a row then it return the wrong output(i.e: 0). How can it be resolved??

Answer (score 0):

Try below 2 ways to get selected item and items.

```
var e = dijit.byId("addressMapStoreGrid");
    if (e.focus.rowIndex < 0) {
        alert('Please select one row!');
        return;
    }
```

-

```
var items = grid.selection.getSelected();
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt help...I have tried the above code but the issue still persist..Actually their are two things :user first click(left click) on a row and then right clicks , it return the correct output(i.e: 1). If user directly right clicks on a row then it return the wrong output(i.e: 0). How can it be resolved??

Comment: @user2927223 this is because that row isn't selected at that moment so you can't use the `.getSelected()` method. You could select the row first when a user right clicks.